# Scroll div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a `<div>`, divided into 3 `<div>`s. Two of those divs are taken as previous and next buttons, having ids `prev` and `next` respectively. 3 `<div>`s having ids `diva`, `divb`, and `divc` are arranged on the bottom. `divb` and `divc` have 0 width so that they are hidden and only `diva` is visible. I want to hide `diva` to hide (set width to 0) and `divb` to appear when user click `id=next` and if the button is clicked again, I want `divb` to hide and `divc` to appear. Also I want this to happen reverse if `id=prev` is clicked.

Below is an image of what I am trying to say;

[image]

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/tHZLY/)** is the fiddle.

Comment: Somebody do me another favor?? I want the text in <a id="middle">content1</a> to change to content2 and content3 respectively.. jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/3yrsu/2 .. Somebody help me please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used class to implement what you need. Check [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/tHZLY/2/) here

Full code:

```
var $pages = $('.page');
$('#nxt').click(
  function() {
    var $cur = $('.active');       //get current active
    var $next = $cur.next();       //get next to cur

    /*
     * Add logic inside below if condition for going 
     * back to first div.
    */
    if ($next.length == 0) return; //if nothing in next, return.

    $cur.removeClass('active');    //remove active class from cur active
    $next.addClass('active');      //add next as current active

    //animate everything except .active (which is next)
    $('.page').not('.active').animate({"width": 0}, "slow"); 

    //animate cur (which was next) 
    $('.active').animate({"width": 200}, "slow");
});

$('#prev').click(
  function() {
    var $cur = $('.active');
    var $prev = $cur.prev('.page');

    if ($prev.length == 0) return;

    $cur.removeClass('active');
    $prev.addClass('active');

    $('.page').not('.active').animate({"width": 0}, "slow");
    $('.active').animate({"width": 200}, "slow");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3yrsu/1/

Added a custom attribute 'current' to keep track of your current slide. Also added a class to identify your slides easily.

HTML:

```
<div class="scroll">
    <div class="buttons">
        <a id="prev">prev</a>
        <a id="middle">test</a>
        <a id="nxt">next</a>
    </div>
    <div id="diva" class="slide" current="1">div AA</div>
    <div id="divb" class="slide">div BB</div>
    <div id="divc" class="slide">div CC</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#nxt').click(
function() {

    var current = $('.slide[current="1"]');
    var next = current.next('.slide');
    var prev = current.prev('.slide');
    if(next.length == 0) {
        next = $('.slide').first().insertAfter(current);
    }
    if(prev.length == 0) {
        prev = $('.slide').last().insertBefore(current);
    }

    current.animate({"width": 0}, "slow");
    next.animate({"width": 200}, "slow");
    prev.animate({"width": 0}, "slow");

    $('.slide').removeAttr('current');
    next.attr('current', "1");

});

$('#prev').click(
function() {

    var current = $('.slide[current="1"]');
    var next = current.prev('.slide');
    var prev = current.next('.slide');

    if(next.length == 0) {
        next = $('.slide').last().insertBefore(current);
    }
    if(prev.length == 0) {
        prev = $('.slide').first().insertAfter(current);
    }

    current.animate({"width": 0}, "slow");
    next.animate({"width": 200}, "slow");
    prev.animate({"width": 0}, "slow");

    $('.slide').removeAttr('current');
    next.attr('current', "1");

});
```

Comment: Hi @techfoobar, can you do me another favor?? I want the text in `<a id="middle">content1</a>` to change to `content2` and `content3` respectively.. http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/3yrsu/2/ .. Can you help me please..

Answer (score 1):

I added class "current" and "page" to your html. You need to change your html to :

```
<div class="scroll">
   <div class="buttons">
       <a id="prev">prev</a>
       <a id="middle">test</a>
        <a id="nxt">next</a>
    </div>
    <div id="diva" class="current page">div AA</div>
    <div id="divb" class="page">div BB</div>
    <div id="divc" class="page">div CC</div>
</div>
```

Your Js code to :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#nxt').click(function() {
    var $cur = $('.current');
    var $next = $cur.next();
    if ($next.length == 0) 
       return false;

    $cur.removeClass('current');
    $next.addClass('current');

    $('.page').not('.current').animate({"width": 0}, "slow");
    $('.current').animate({"width": 200}, "slow");
  });

  $('#prev').click(function() {
     var $cur = $('.current');
     var $prev = $cur.prev('.page');

     if ($prev.length == 0) 
       return false;

     $cur.removeClass('current');
     $prev.addClass('current');

     $('.page').not('.current').animate({"width": 0}, "slow");
     $('.current').animate({"width": 200}, "slow");
  });
 });
```

Working demo http://jsfiddle.net/FGGBH/

Hope this helps :)